# JavaFX - image, imageview an

Tags: java, image, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

i'm trying to create the game called "Othello". I created a button in scenebuilder to restart the game. 
I have a gridPane [from 0 to 7][from 0 to 7] (dim-array) and every block, for example myGridPane[i][j] a image viewer with a image inside whose contains my pieces(black or white). I have some errors..But i can't understand what i wrong. Help me, please thank you.

ERROR WHEN I PRESS "RESTART GAME BUTTON"

```
> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:620)
    at othello.controller.BoardController.restartGame(BoardController.java:72)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
    ... 64 more
```

My board code

```
@FXML
   private void restartGame(ActionEvent event)throws Exception{
      myGrid = new GridPane();
      black = new Image("images/black.png");
      white = new Image("images/white.png");
      empty = new Image("images/empty.png");
      ImageView square = new ImageView();
      square.setImage(empty);
      ImageView blackSquare = new ImageView();
      blackSquare.setImage(black);
      ImageView whiteSquare = new ImageView();
      whiteSquare.setImage(white);
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){ //Per righe
         for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){ // Per colonne
            myGrid.add(square, i, j);
         }

      }
      myGrid.add(blackSquare, 3, 3);
      myGrid.add(blackSquare, 4, 3);
      myGrid.add(whiteSquare, 4, 4);
      myGrid.add(whiteSquare, 4, 3);
   }
```

Path:

```
I have main project in src of netbeans.
Inside it, i have:
- othello (it contains my main)
- othello.images (it cointains all my image also backgrounds)
- othello.view (it contains my FXML files)
- othello.model (now nothing)
- othello.controller (it contains the controllers about the fxml files)
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the application?

Comment: The problem seems to be at `othello.controller.BoardController.restartGame(BoardController.java:72)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `Image` class [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html):

> All URLs supported by URL can be passed to the constructor. If the passed string is not a valid URL, but a path instead, the Image is searched on the classpath in that case.

So your image paths `images/black.png` will be searched relative to the classpath, and clearly there is no `images` resource at the root of the classpath. You need

```
new Image("othello/images/black.png")
```

etc.

Since your `Main` class is in the `othello` package, another option would be to get the resource relative to that, e.g.

```
new Image(Main.class.getResource("images/black.png"))
```

etc.

Note you have further errors, which are not showing yet as the code is failing before you reach them. You cannot add the same node to the scene graph more than once, so

```
  myGrid.add(blackSquare, 3, 3);
  myGrid.add(blackSquare, 4, 3);
```

will throw an `IllegalStateException` with the message "duplicate child added", since you are adding `blackSquare` multiple times to the scene graph. You need to create a new `ImageView` for each square in the grid (you can use the same `Image` in different `ImageView`s if you like).

So you should do:

```
@FXML
private void restartGame(ActionEvent event)throws Exception{
  myGrid = new GridPane();
  black = new Image(Main.class.getResource("images/black.png"));
  white = new Image(Main.class.getResource("images/white.png"));
  empty = new Image(Main.class.getResource("images/empty.png"));
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){ //Per righe
     for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){ // Per colonne
        myGrid.add(square, i, j);
     }

  }
  myGrid.add(new ImageView(black), 3, 3);
  myGrid.add(new ImageView(black), 4, 3);
  myGrid.add(new ImageView(white), 4, 4);
  myGrid.add(new ImageView(white), 4, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL**. You are not giving a valid image URL. Let's say i want to display an image called boldedRow.png and boldedRow.png happens to be inside view folder, and my main java file is in src directory then i can get the image url in the following way.

Structure of Program:
src directory:

-->ShowImage.java

-->view / boldedRow.png

```
public class ShowImage extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        ImageView image = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("view/boldedRow.png")));
        root.getChildren().add(image);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: However, in this case the OP can't get a reference relative to the current class, as the package containing the image is not a subpackage of the package containing the current class. (You can try `getResourceAsStream("../images/black.png")`, which might work when the class loader is loading from the file system, but will fail when the class loader is loading, e.g. from a jar file, as `..` is not a valid resource name.)

Comment: ok, never loaded an image from other jar file before. Thanks for the info. I will remember it.

Comment: It's not from another jar file, it's just from a package that is not a subpackage of the current one. The OP says the current class is in `othello.controller` and the images are in `othello.images`. `othello.images` is not a subpackage of `othello.controller`. So the method you describe here won't work (or, at the very least, isn't guaranteed to work).

Answer (score -2):

Use this code to get the image

```
    File f = new File("images/black.png");
    Image img = new Image(f.toURI().toString());
```

Comment: That will search relative to the working directory, so it will only work if the working directory happens to be the parent of `images` (which it probably isn't). And it will not work under any circumstances once the application is bundled as a jar file (since the images will no longer be files at all, but entries in the jar file).